# Copy some data from sqlite table to the same table with different two columns

Tags: sqlite, copy

Let say I have table T with columns A,B,C,D,E,F 
 
A is autoincrement primary key 
 
I have there some data 
 
I want to copy all data where B=x 
 
I want to copy data to the same table but while copying set A to null (so it can create  new IDs) and change B to y.  
 
Example:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F  
1,1,9,8,3,9 
2,1,0,3,2,2 
3,1,7,1,1,8 
4,2,5,4,7,5 
5,2,6,5,8,4 
6,3,9,4,5,3
```

```
 x = 2, y = 4
```

Result:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F 
1,1,9,8,3,9  
2,1,0,3,2,2 
3,1,7,1,1,8 
4,2,5,4,7,5 
5,2,6,5,8,4 
6,3,9,4,5,3 
7,4,5,4,7,5  
8,4,6,5,8,4
```

I found one solution 
 
Create table Temp as select * from T where B = x 
 
Then 
 
Update T set A = null, B = y  
 
Then Insert into T select * from Temp 
 
Then drop table temp

I didn't test but it should work, but is there easier way or can it be written in one single query?

Comment: The solution does not belong into the question; create an answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution, maybe not the best but quite good:

```
INSERT INTO T (A,B,C,D,E,F) SELECT null,y,C,D,E,F from T WHERE B = x
```